# Want to join table1 with table2 but want output of rows in the same sequence as in table2, but I am getting output as in table1

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

**Datatype here is string and not integer.**

hive> **select * from table1;**
OK

```
2,       1 \t
2,       2 \t
2,       3 \t
2,       4 \t
2,       5 \t
3,       1 \t
3,       2 \t
3,       3 \t
3,       4 \t
3,       5 \t
4,       1 \t
4,       2 \t
4,       3 \t
4,       4 \t
4,       5 \t
5,       1 \t
5,       2 \t
5,       3 \t
5,       4 \t
5,       5 \t
6,       1 \t
6,       2 \t
6,       3 \t
6,       4 \t
6,       5 \t
```

hive> **select * from table2;**
OK

```
3,       1 \t
3,       2 \t
4,       2 \t
4,       1 \t
4,       0 \t
```

In then above table I want only rows in the following sequence as inn table2:
OK
**3,       1 \t
3,       2 \t
4,       2 \t
4,       1 \t**

But when I run below query I get different result.
**select t2.col1, t2.col2 from table2 t2 join table1 t1 on t2.col1=t1.col1 where t2.col2=t1.col2;**
OK

```
3,       1 \t
3,       2 \t
4,       **1** \t
4,       **2** \t
```

What should be the correct Hive query to get results as they are in sequence in table2.

Comment: Rows represent unordered sets. There is no sequence as such except that provided by an ORDER BY clause

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Hadoop, Hive, or all 3?  You seriously need to clean up your labels.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using HiveQL for this

Comment: Hi @Strawberry when I use order by command I get the following output:  **select t2.col1, t2.col2 from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.col1=t1.col1 where t2.col2=t1.col2 order by t2.col1, t2.col2;** OK
3,       1 \t
3,       2 \t
4,       1 \t
4,       2 \t

Answer (score 0):

RDBMS tables represent unsorted sets of data. The order rows are returned is arbitrary, and may in fact change if the table is exported/imported, indexres are rebuilt, some state of some internal cache changes, etc.

If the order of rows is important to you, you must explicitly specify the order you need in an `order by` clause.

Comment: Hi @Mureinik when I use order by command I get the following output: **select t2.col1, t2.col2 from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.col1=t1.col1 where t2.col2=t1.col2 order by t2.col1, t2.col2;** OK 3, 1 \t 3, 2 \t 4, 1 \t 4, 2 \t